# How to hide this feature in pycharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

[image: pycharm message]

It's really annoying, it appeared with new `pycharm` version. How can I hide this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the **Show breadcrumbs** option:

[image: show breadcrumbs]